# Webelement get null values using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, frameworks

I am trying to open mail in gmail for verifying the link on "www.gmail.com" and registration has been done from "www.abc.com", so how can we recognize the mail using selenium WebDriver with keyword driven framework.

I have made two methods in one method it contains all the keywords with operation and in another method it contains location.

But whenever the execution is going on I am not able to click on mail for opening because in WebElement it get null.

So, can anyone please check that I have declare the syntax properly or not? Or why I don't get the value?

**Below are the code:**

```
private boolean operateWebDriver(String operation, String Locator,String value, String objectName) throws Exception {
    boolean testCaseStep = false;

    try {
        System.out.println("Operation execution in progress");
        WebElement temp = getElement(Locator, objectName);

        //Trying to click on email.
        if(operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Click_anElement")){

            if(temp.equals(value)){
                temp.click();
            }
        }

        //Trying to verify email.
        if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Verify_Email")) {
            System.out.println("Verify--->" + temp);
            if(temp.equals(value)){
                System.out.println("Verified");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Not Verified");
            }
        }
        testCaseStep = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception occurred operateWebDriver"+ e.getMessage());

        // Take screenshot if any test-case is not working. 
        System.out.println("Taking Screen Shot");
        TakesScreenshot ts=(TakesScreenshot)driver;
        File source=ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File("./Screenshots/"+screenshotName+".png"));
        System.out.println("Screenshot taken");
    }
    return testCaseStep;
}

public WebElement getElement(String locator, String objectName) throws Exception {
    WebElement temp = null;
    System.out.println("Locator-->" + locator);
    if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
        temp = driver.findElement(By.id(objectName));
    }
    else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath")) {
        temp = driver.findElement(By.xpath(objectName));
        System.out.println("xpath temp ----->" + temp);
    }
    else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath1")){
        String row_xpath_end= "]";
        for(int rowNum=1; rowNum<=10; rowNum++){
            temp = driver.findElement(By.xpath(objectName+rowNum+row_xpath_end));
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

**Error:**

```
Exception occurred operateWebDriverThe given selector /html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[7]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[ is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression /html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[7]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[ because of the following error:
[Exception... "The expression is not a legal expression."  code: "12" nsresult: "0x805b0033 (SyntaxError)"  location: "file:///C:/DOCUME~1/Chayan/LOCALS~1/Temp/anonymous1831932369561342639webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js Line: 5934"]
Command duration or timeout: 16 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:18:15'
System info: host: 'aa-ff7b4a68', ip: '192.168.1.3', os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.7.0_71'
Session ID: 051985f9-6320-4d0f-ad48-0ab3ff975f02
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=18.0}]
Taking Screen Shot
```

Comment: Does it enter one of the `if` options in `getElement()`?

Comment: @Guy Actually its not able to find the element in line "temp = driver.findElement(By.xpath(objectName+rowNum+row_xpath_end));". Can you please give some solution for it? Also I have post the error which I get please check.

Comment: The `xpath` you provided ends with `tr[` so you get an error `"The expression is not a legal expression."`. Are you sure it doesn't go into the second if? `else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath"))`

Comment: @Guy Actually it should goes to line else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath1")) because the logic for opening the mail is written here and then, it goes to method name "operateWebDriver''. In these it get the value(Mail subject line) and then click on it. This is I am trying to do.

Comment: I understand where it should go, my question is does it really goes there or goes to `else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath"))`? because judging from the error it looks like the later is what happened.

Comment: @Guy 1. It goes in else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath1")) which is correct.
2. As I debug the program then I also found that its not finding the keyword which I have give, but in my excel keyword is also same.

Comment: If you look at the error `/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[7]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[` is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement` you can see that the driver is looking for `xpath` with ends with `tr[`, witch is invalid  locator. My guess is that this isthe variable `objectName`, thats why I think it goes to the other `if else`.

Comment: @Guy The reason behind this xpath given is, in mail we first find out the row number of each mail. So for that i have given an xpath upto row and then apply for() loop to find the number and then end it. Now if they found the value(subject line of email) in any of the row then they click on it and mail will be open. This is how it should have to work

Comment: As a side note, relying on xpath like `/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[7]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody` is a terrible idea. First of all any slight change on the page, and it will be broken, secondly it's very hard to understand what you are looking for and so on. I'd spend time to find some more logical xpath (e.g. using id, class some attributes, not the position of the xpath on the page)

Comment: GMail has a proper API: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/ that could eliminate much of this complexity, duplication, and brittleness.

Comment: @KirilS. So, can you please suggest with sample code, jow can we open the mail? Because for verifying the link, its mandatory to open the mail.

Comment: Any solution @Guy to resolved my problem or any alternative?

Comment: Make it a habit to use short path that is easy to identify. Guy gave you a good example of how to use css selectors. Here are some examples of using xpath, if you prefer xpath over css selectors: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Inbox']")).click();` - clicks on inbox; `List<WebElement> emailSubjects = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id=':8q']//div[@role='link']"));` - provides you with list of email subjects, from where you can click on them just link in Guy's code : `emailSubjects.get(0).click();`

Comment: @KirilS. I am agree with you comment that we have to take short path, but at the time of executing a program it register the account from "www.abc.com" and receive a mail at "www.gmail.com" that time how we recognize that mail and click on it, because that time it create the new class body for new mail.

Answer (score 0):

You can locate all the mails using common class `xY a4W` and click by index

```
List<WebElement> mails = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".xY.a4W")); // finds the mail body
mails.get(0).click(); // open first mail
```

You can also locate all the mails from specific sender

```
String name = "name";
List<WebElement> mails = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='zF'][@name='" + name + "']/../..");
mails.get(0).click();
```

This will open the first mail with name "name".

Comment: We can locate all the mail with common class and in that class it generate the different id of each mail, but at the time of executing a program it register the account from "www.abc.com" and receive a mail at "www.gmail.com" that time how we recognize that mail and click on it?

Comment: How we can do the same without using List< >, because as you see my code I have used WebElement with their object and return it. So, in one method how we can return the object of two class? its not possible.. :(

Comment: @SelenyanC2 Because the id is random there isn't way to locate only one specific element. The best thing you can do is to get only the emails from one sender and from there take the first using index 0.

Comment: Can you please provide the sample code using the way I am doing because I am trying to resolve this problem but not getting the solution. Thanks in advance..

Comment: @SelenyanC2 In `getElement()` replace `temp = driver.findElement(By.id(objectName));` with `temp = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='zF'][@name='" + name + "']/../..").get(0);`

Comment: I get this error: Operation execution in progress
Locator-->xpath1
Exception occurred operateWebDriverIndex: 1, Size: 0
Taking Screen Shot
Screenshot taken

Comment: @SelenyanC2 Where?

Comment: When it pass from "temp = driver.findElements(By.xpath(objectName)).get(1);" and in object name it contain ".//*[@id=':2p']/td[4]".

Comment: @SelenyanC2 Object name is the name of who sent the mail as it appears in the in box, not a xpath.

Comment: As per my created excel in object name column all the element locators are stored.

Comment: @SelenyanC2 I don't understand the last comment.

Comment: As I mentioned that I am working with Keyword driven framework. So, in my excel of "Object repository" it contains the column with name "Object name", in these all the xpath, id, name is contained. Hope you understand now.

Comment: @SelenyanC2 ok I get it. The `name` in my answer is local variable witch contains the name of who sent the email. There is no connection to the excel file.

Comment: here is the line which I write in getElement(), "temp = driver.findElements(By.xpath(objectName)).get(1);". Now just want to let you know that in my repository it contain the value or name from where I received the mail, please let me know how can I pass it. Also, one question in mind that after registration with other site, we don't know the xpath of that mail. So, the best solution which you told previously with common class is good. Its my request to you please let me know the line of code by using the common class, but in the way of my code structure.

Comment: waiting for your kind reply.

Answer (score 0):

I have use this code for getting password from gmail 
but you have need to update xpath (check once)

```
WebElement tableelement=DriverObj.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='Cp']/div/table//tbody"));
            java.util.List<WebElement> tableelement1=tableelement.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='Cp']/div/table//tbody/tr"));
            int tableelementsize=tableelement1.size();
            int i;
            if(tableelementsize>0){
                //DriverObj.navigate().refresh();
                for(i=0;i<tableelementsize;i++){
                    DriverObj.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='Cp']/div/table//tbody/tr/td[6]")).click();
                }

            }else {
                 if(tableelementsize==0){
                    DriverObj.navigate().refresh();
                    for(i=0;i<tableelementsize;i++){
                        DriverObj.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='Cp']/div/table//tbody/tr/td[6]")).click();
                    }
                }
            }
```